# Python - Extracting cell value from raster within shapes and association polygon id

Tags: python, shapefile

I am pretty new to geospatial data and need to do some data extraction.

I have GeoTIFF raster data containing precipitation value and catchment area in the form of shapefile. Within each shapefile there are multiple polygons with specific POLY_ID.

This is the raster data

[image: Raster Data]

And this is how the shapefile looks like

[image: Catchment Shapefile]

I need to extract value from each cell that falls within a polygon and return the coordinate, the cell value as well as the POLY_ID for further computation against predetermined cell weight.

I used rioxarray to convert the raster data into geoDataFrame and performed spatial join with the catchment data but the result does not seem to be correct.

```
def process_rds(raster, gdf_catchment, cell_weight, cell_area_list):

# open raster file and convert to GeoDF
with rx.open_rasterio(raster) as raster_data:
    raster_data.name = "precipitation"
    raster_df = raster_data.to_dataframe().reset_index()
    geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(raster_df.x, raster_df.y)
    gdf_precip = gpd.GeoDataFrame(raster_df, crs=raster_data.rio.crs, geometry=geometry)

# perform spatial join with catchment data
new_gdf = gpd.sjoin(gdf_precip, gdf_catchment, how = 'left', predicate = 'within') 
# convert to pandas DF
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_gdf)

# merge against cell_weight to get weighted precipitation
merged_df = cell_weight.merge(new_df, on = ['x', 'y'], how='left') 
merged_df['weighted_precip'] = merged_df['precipitation'] * merged_df['coverage_fraction']

# Aggregate by POLY_ID to get total catchment area based precipitation
df_weighted_precip = merged_df.groupby(['POLY_ID_x']).aggregate({'weighted_precip': sum}).reset_index()

# Obtain the mean precipitation (weighted_precip / cell_area)
df_weighted_precip['mean_precip'] = df_weighted_precip['weighted_precip']/cell_area_df['Area']

return df_weighted_precip
```

What is the right way to perform such task?

Comment: How I've done this previously in very simplified steps: Rasterize the polygon with the same cell size and dimension as your existing raster, open the polygon raster for read, read as numpy array, loop through the values: where the value is a background value do nothing, where the value is not background access the existing array at that row/column index. The other way is to loop through your data and calculate the world coordinate using the GeoTransform and check for *inside* with OGR. 3rd option convert your raster to points and use clip to trim the feature class to only those values inside.

Comment: Your choice depends on how large your source data is, if you've only got a few hundred valid pixel values then go for Raster->Point and clip, if your input value raster is a few thousand rows and columns then it's probably worth the effort required to implement the first method.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, probably a few thousand valid pixel values.. i can mask the data using rasterio. But my expected output is a dataframe which contains the x and y centroid of each cell, the cell value and also the POLY_ID from shapefile used to mask.. i cannot seem to achieve this. any suggestion on how to go about it?

Comment: Sorry, not with rioxarray, I've not used that. Your question asks for values of cells inside, if you're really after a rioxarray dataframe perhaps your question needs some rewording to make your goal clearer. Previously I've used GDAL to access cell values within polygons but can't help with rioxarray sorry.